# the value of a pointer in a function

Tags: c, pointers

Hi I am learning about pointers in C and wondered what does the code below do?
Does the pointer `*abc` just points to some random stuff because it is not properly assigned with an address of a variable?

```c
   void func()
   {
      int *abc;
      *abc = 5;
   }
```

Comment: The code will simply invoke undefined behaviour when run.

Comment: It's undefined behavior, since you're assigning to the target of `abc` before you have assigned a pointer value to it.

Comment: Yes. It points to some random stuff. If it happens to point to valid memory you'll overwrite something else. If it is not you'll get a segmentation fault and the program will crash.

Comment: Until a pointer is initialized to point to a valid memory location, the pointer is an "*uninitialized pointer*" holding some indeterminate address as its value. When you assign a valid address to the pointer, you *initialize* the pointer to point to that valid address (*a pointer is just a normal variable that holds the memory address to something else as its value*, i.e. the pointer points to that address). So in your case if you have `int i = 5, *abc = &i;` you initialize `abc` (make it point) to the address in memory where `5` is stored.

Answer (score 0):

As you note, `abc` is not properly initialized, so we do not know what it points to. Before it can be reliably used, it must be assigned a value that is the address of properly reserved memory. You can assign it a value by assigning it the address of a defined object (as in `int x; int *abc = &x;`) or by requesting memory through a routine such as `malloc` (as in `int *abc = malloc(sizeof *abc);` and checking that the result is not `NULL`).

Note that it is not correct to say that it “points to random stuff.” In the terms of the C standard, its value is indeterminate. This means its value is not only unspecified, but that a program that uses it might behave as if `abc` has a different value each time it is used—it does not necessarily act as if `abc` has some single randomly determined value. It might also have a trap representation, which does not represent a value of pointer type, and using it would result in the behavior of the program not being defined by the C standard.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assigning a value to pointer with assigning memory, which leads to segmentation fault.

```
int *abc;
```

Above statement will just declare a pointer to integer, but it does not hold any address.

```
int *abc = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
*abc = 5;
```

If you want to assign a value directly, You need to initialize with some memory.
Only then you can assign directly

Comment: `*abc = 5;` is not necessarily a *segmentation fault*. It is **undefined behavior** which may lead to anything.

Comment: And `free(abc);` to be clean.

Comment: and check for `NULL`  - `malloc()` can return a `NULL` if an error occurs allocating memory.